# wp-customer-reviews plugin trouble while showing reviews in admin

Tags: wordpress

I am using plugin wp customer reviews. It is working fine, but the only trouble am facing is that in the backend when i click on reviews, it shows the correct number of reviews but am not able to actually view the reviews. Here is the [link](http://creativescripters.com/samples/Untitled.png) where i have attached the screenshot of the backend. Can anyone help me please, why is this happening. I have tried by removing the plugin and installing the plugin again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might know this answer. Go to your settings and read the portion on shortcode. You need to change the number there from 3 to whatever you want to show. It is pretty easy.